# как работают квадратные скобки в javascript

Tags: javascript

Я новичок в js, недавно наткнулся на такой код

```
let a = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ];
let b = 0;
() => {
  if (b + 1 < 5) {
    a[b] = 0;
    a[b + 1] = 1;
    b++;
  }
}
```

Насколько мне известно, `[ ]` это объект, не могу понять что означает `a[b] = 0`, и как вообще эта функция работает без цикла.

Comment: Скобочки в разных местах имеют разное значение и никак не связаны. Просто `[чтототам]` это создание массива с элементами, а `объект[чтототам]` это получение значения свойства объекта по его имени

Comment: это не код, а извращение какое-то...

Comment: @HamSter, :-D что-то я ничего не понял

Answer (score 2):

> Насколько мне известно, [] это объект...

[Объекты →](https://learn.javascript.ru/object)

[Массивы →](https://learn.javascript.ru/array)

Объект (он же: Ассоциативный массив), вот:

```js
let obj = {
  "bubu": "BUBU!",
  "0": "a",
  "1": "b",
  "2": "c",
  "3": "d"
};

console.log(obj.bubu);   // "BUBU!"
console.log( obj[0] );   // "a"
console.log( obj["0"] ); // "a"

// console.log( obj.0 ); // ошибка
```

Хранит пары "ключ": "Значение". Знечения могут быть какими угодно, а ключи - только строками. Если ключ - обычная строка без специальных символов и пробелов, и не начинается с цифры, его значение можно достать через оператор-"точку". Для всех других случаев предусмотрена "скобочная нотация": Когда ключ записывается внутри квадратных скобок, сперва вычисляется, преобразуется в строку, а потом уже достается из объекта.

Т.е., будет работать и такой вариант:

```js
var qs = "querySelector";
document[ qs ]('p')["style"]["background" + "Color"] = "orange";
// document.querySelector('p').style.backgroundColor = "orange";
```

```html
<p>Работает!</p>
```

Но если ключ-обычная строка, используют точку, т.к. это просто короче.

`let a = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0];` — а вот это, в JS называют просто "массив" (нумерованный список), особый тип объекта, у которого все ключи - числовые строки ("0", "1", "2"...) и спрятаны для удобства. И чтобы достать их значения, к массиву обращаются как к объекту, через скобки: `a[0], a[1], a[2]`...

P.s. а функция - не работает) Она просто объявлена и висит...

Comment: _а ключи - только строками_ и Symbol

Answer (score 0):

Квадратные скобки - это массив.

В начале объявляется массив `a` и переменная равная 0.

Далее идёт стрелочная функция в которой проверяется условие, и в случае возврата true ячейке `b` (которая в данном случае является нулём) массива `a` присваивается значение 0, а дальше следующей ячейке значение 1, а далее переменная `b` инкрементируется.

Это основы, без которых дальше никуда.