# JavaScript Что делают квадратные скобки?

Tags: javascript, массивы

```js
let block = document.querySelector('.block')
console.log(block);
console.log([block]);
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <span>123</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, quidem?</p>
</div>
```

Вывод в кадратных скобках выводит элемент как массив?

Comment: Квадратные скобки создают массив

Comment: В чём конкретно вопрос? Что происходит когда вы запускаете ваш код в консоли? Как минимум в FF сразу пишет в консоли что это массив

Comment: Вот есть аналогичный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1111878/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-javascript

Comment: @andreymal не совсем, они как создают массив, так используя их можно рефериться к элементам массива.

Comment: @ΝNL993 это в случае если массив указан перед ними, тут иное

Comment: @DaniilLoban не совсем, к примеру также можно обращаться и к объектам, пример: `window['document']`

Comment: @ΝNL993 где вы в коде видете что-то из перечисленного?, вопрос на пол копейки а комментов уже простыня))))

Comment: @DaniilLoban я просто привёл для это как пример альтернативного использования, не более того.